# Unable to Retrieve Registration Page Content from Twitter Website using Python Requests

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

Introduction:

I am facing a challenge while attempting to retrieve the content of the registration page for the Twitter website using Python Requests module. Despite running the code, the expected content of the page is not being returned, leaving me perplexed and seeking expert advice to resolve this issue.

Problem Description:

I am currently working on a Python script to scrape data from the Twitter website, specifically the registration page. To do this, I am employing the Python Requests library, which is commonly used for making HTTP requests and fetching web page content. However, I have encountered an unexpected hurdle as the code execution does not yield the expected result of the registration page content.

Code Sample:
Below is the code snippet I have implemented to access the registration page content:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({
    'accept':'*/*',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'content-type':'application/json',
    'origin':'https://twitter.com',
    'referer':'https://twitter.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua':'"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile':'?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform':'"Windows"',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
})


req = s.get('https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup', timeout=20, allow_redirects=True) 
print(req.text)
```

For your information, the code you shared with me was working perfectly fine, but today I was surprised to find it stopped working, and everything that used the requests library has also stopped. I need a solution using the requests library.